# Java Swing Menu Click

Tags: java, swing

I have some problem swing menu click event.

I want to click 'My Status' how can I handle this please help me.

For example about this image, I want to add click event for system tools.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Menu item is a simple button. So, ther are `ActionListener`

Comment: @The_Programmer Great suggestion. A tip: `[mcve]` in a comment auto-expands to [mcve].

Comment: @oleg.cherednik I tried but isn't work. Actually the problem is that, I want to use system tray. if I use MenuItem in MenuBar I cant use actionevent. But if I use JMenuItem in MenuBar I can use. So system tray provide just MenuItem not JMenuItem.

Comment: I think I can help (I faced with this many years ago). Could you provide a complete short application with this problem. I could look at it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is a short example for my application.

List<Menu> menuItems = new ArrayList<>();
    for (File file : files) {
        Menu menuItem = new Menu();
        menuItem.setLabel(file.getName());
        menuItem.setName(file.getPath());
        menuItems.add(menuItem);
       menuItem.addActionListener(newMenuItemClickActions(menuItem));
    }
```